# How do I resolve the following plugin error when loading Codeblocks

Tags: plugins, codeblocks

Whenever I start *Code::Blocks* I get the following message:

### [image: *Plugin " " failed to load last time Code::Blocks was executed.Do you want to disable this plugin from loading?*]

Choosing *yes* or *no* does not make any difference, the message still shows up next time.

How do I find out which plugin is causing the problem?
I am running *Code::Blocks* 10.5 on fedora 17

Answer (score 0):

You can see all plugins installed in Code::Blocks -> Plugins -> Manage plugins.
If you find a plugin named "", then I would think it's safe to remove that one.

But I doubt that. You will probably have to disable all plugins and enable them, one by one, restarting Code::Blocks in-between until you find the plugin causing you the error above.